# Gantt Style Tablix in Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, gantt-chart

I have successfully been able to create a Gantt Chart using Charting in Reporting Service 2008 R2.

However is something similar possible in a tablix? What I want to achieve is I have a project with specific taskIDs with start and end dates. I want to list the task description but then the subsequent columns would be weeks and coloured depending if the task range fits within this as in the example attached. Another problem I have is that I have Major and Minor tasks. The minor tasks having ParentIDs. Any pointers of how to get started with this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the dataset field with the weeks is called "Week" you can polpulate your matrix with this field on the "Columns" cell and the "Data" cell.
Take note of the name of the column text box and the data text box (lets say the are named "Week" and "Week1").
Thes you can use the following expression to populate the Font and Fill properties of the the data cell:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Week.Value=ReportItems!Week1.Value,"Red","White")
```

this should produce the effect of the populated cells as being filled with a solid colour.